# css3 grey image to blue color using filters?

Tags: html, css, colors

I'm trying to get a grey image to a more blue tone, really no idea how to set the filters for this or if it's possible.

The image only has one color in `#cacaca`, the rest transparent. I'm trying to do some overlay with the same image so that it only highlights those colored parts and not the transparent areas.

Been playing with some of these but not much success, no idea what I'm doing when it comes to colors.

```
.saturate {-webkit-filter: saturate(3); filter: saturate(3);}
.grayscale {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);}
.contrast {-webkit-filter: contrast(160%); filter: contrast(160%);}
.brightness {-webkit-filter: brightness(0.25); filter: brightness(0.25);}
.blur {-webkit-filter: blur(3px); filter: blur(3px);}
.invert {-webkit-filter: invert(100%); filter: invert(100%);}
.sepia {-webkit-filter: sepia(100%); filter: sepia(100%);}
.huerotate {-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg); filter: hue-rotate(180deg);}
.rss.opacity {-webkit-filter: opacity(50%); filter: opacity(50%);}
```

Comment: what output do you need? Can you share the image ouput?

Comment: If you can use html5 canvas, then you can loop through each image pixel and replace its colors.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use a combination of:

- `filter: sepia()`
- `filter: hue-rotate()`
- `filter: saturate()`

**Working Example:**

```css
img {
width: 107px;
height: 180px;
}

img.filtered {
filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(190deg) saturate(500%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/16/19/16/png-1096410_960_720.png" alt="I am a plant" />

<img class="filtered" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/16/19/16/png-1096410_960_720.png" alt="I am a plant" />
```

Comment: Doesn't this just work because the original image actually _has_ color?

Comment: Ah, no it doesn't, via tested with http://xzdl43v0mdf2m45tz2aj7kkv35.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/grey-780x400.jpg

Comment: The trick is to use the `sepia()` filter to ensure that an otherwise grayscale picture _does_ have color. And then the `hue-rotate()` filter will work.

Comment: Managed to get this with the greyscale by removing some of the brightness for a darker blue `filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(140deg) brightness(60%) saturate(500%);`

Comment: for a bit lighter blue i found that one good: `filter:sepia(27%) hue-rotate(184deg) saturate(9);`

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to set colors more directly via the SVG filter trapdoor.

```css
img {
width: 107px;
height: 180px;
}

img.filtered {
filter: url(#blue-wash);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/16/19/16/png-1096410_960_720.png" alt="I am a plant" />

<img class="filtered" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/16/19/16/png-1096410_960_720.png" alt="I am a plant" />

<svg>
<filter id="blue-wash" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.2 0.2 0.2 0 0   0.3 0.3 0.3 0 0  1 1 1 0 0  0 0 0 1 0"/>
</filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: How does this matrix work? I would like to allow the use choose their own color and I'm happy to use whatever format is needed

Comment: The values are the unitized R (0.2)  G (0.3) and B(1.0) values that you want to convert the grey image to - so that would be equivalent to roughly rgb(51, 76, 255): aka 255*.02 ; 255*.02; 255*1.0

Answer (score 0):

shorter code will be:

```
filter: brightness(1) invert(0);
```